# How to install networkx on activepython community edition?

Tags: python, networkx, activepython

I am attempting to run the command easy_install networkx to install the NetworkX package. When I do it generates this error message: 
        `SyntaxError: invalid syntax`.
Is it because I am using the free community edition of activepython or am I making a stupid mistake?

Comment: well ... i am also using free version of activestate python2.7. and also installed `networkx` without any error. can you post the error trackback and complete `easy_install` command with Networkx as its argument.

Comment: Thanks namit! I was making the mistake of writing the command in the Interactive Shell instead of the PyPM Administrator.